# SQL Query Syntax Error - Spaces in Field Names

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, syntax-error

The database my application uses has field names containing spaces.  I believe this to be the cause of my problem.  Here is a typical query:

```
SELECT * FROM 'OV2 BAS' AS bas 
INNER JOIN 'OV2 RefID' AS ids ON 'bas.Ref ID' = 'ids.Ref ID' 
WHERE ids.ENUM_H = 'TDischarge';
```

How do I deal with the spaces in the field names?  Thanks.

***Additional Information***

This is to access a database made with MS Access 2007 (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0).

Comment: This is to access a database made with MS Access 2007 (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you can use quotes around the actual table name; only the name you assign to it. I would wrap the table in brackets instead: `[OV2 BAS]`

You also can't put quotes around your joining syntax either. Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM [OV2 BAS] AS bas INNER JOIN [OV2 RefID] AS ids ON bas.[Ref ID] = ids.[Ref ID] WHERE ids.ENUM_H = 'TDischarge';
```

Answer (score 10):

Replace `'` with

- postgreSQL, Oracle: `"`
- MySQL `` ` ``
- SQL-server: `[` and `]`

For example: `"OV2 BAS"`, `bas."Ref ID" = ids."Ref ID"`, etc.

Comment: +1 as delimiting tablename and column name together definitely seems wrong. Though I'm guessing backticks rather than quotes based on the delimiter used in the question.

Answer (score 2):

For Microsoft Access, wrap field names that contain spaces with back ticks e.g. SELECT `Eng Units` FROM Table

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the database engine you're using.
For SQL Server, you have to put the field names in brackets: `[  ]`

```
SELECT * FROM [OV2 BAS] AS bas 
INNER JOIN [OV2 RefID] AS ids ON bas.[Ref ID] = ids.[Ref ID]
WHERE ids.ENUM_H = 'TDischarge';
```

Comment: This is to access a database made with MS Access 2007 (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0).

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify which DBMS you're using, but I'm guessing SQL server, so

```
SELECT *
FROM [OV2 BAS] AS bas
     ^^^^^^^^^
```

... enclose the field name in brackets. Using quotes as you are, turns the field name into a plain string, which will NOT be treated as a fieldname by SQL server.

Comment: This is to access a database made with MS Access 2007 (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0).

Comment: Ok. brackets'll work there too. Consider renaming your fields so there's no spaces in them if you can - spaced names will cause pain down the road (as you're finding now).

Comment: You'll have to unquote the field names on the JOIN clause as well - quoting field names turns them into strings, and they WON'T be treated as field names. ` ... ON bas.[Ref ID] = ids.[Ref ID]`

Comment: Why do you say "spaced names will cause pain down the road"? As long as you quote your fieldnames (which you should **always** do), it will be fine.

Comment: @rjmunro "As long as you quote, you should be fine"  That's exactly the problem. Not everybody does.  Marc B is correct: putting spaces in field names is not best practice.