# SQL Server SQL SELECT in Python not working when the WHERE clause field contains a space

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, tkinter, pyodbc

[image]I have a field called FieldName. If the FieldName is M then the query works fine. However, if the FieldName is Big Hill then I get None results in my Tkinter Text box. Not sure how to get make sure which one of these I can modify so that the entire result is considered not just the first word. def field_name generates the list of FieldNames. The user chooses one of the FieldNames and this is used in def avg10112 as the WHERE clause. Finally, the results are put in the text box by def insert_AVG10112. This box will display None if the WHERE clause contains a space as explained above(BigHill vs. Big Hill).

Edit: I added a screenshot of the Combobox. The single value fieldNames work and the others(Buffalo Valley), do not work.

```
def avg10112(self):
    sql=("SELECT FORMAT(AVG([DailyCosts].DailyCost),'#,##0') AVG FROM [DailyCosts] "
         "JOIN [WellConfig] ON DailyCosts.[WellID] = WellConfig.[WellID] "
         "WHERE  [FieldName] = ? AND DailyCost IS NOT NULL AND DailyCosts.AccountCode IN('10112','11103','7108') ")
    self.cursor.execute(sql, [self.field_bx.get()])
    row = self.cursor.fetchall()
    return row

def field_Name(self):
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT FieldName FROM WellConfig ")
    row = self.cursor.fetchall()
    return row


def insert_Avg10112(self):
    self.cost102_avg.delete(1.0, 'end')
    for row in self.avg10102():
        self.cost102_avg.insert ('end', row)
```

Comment: Also, now that I have written this all out I see that I have 1.0, 'end'. I am wondering if that is the issue? If so that is the only way I could write it to get the text box to work. I guess I could switch to an entry box.

Comment: If the column name contains a space (or other misc characters like -,/ etc) you must quote them.  For example WHERE [Big Hill]  = ...

Comment: Aren't I already doing that with [self.field_bx.get()]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Query Syntax Error - Spaces in Field Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984124/sql-query-syntax-error-spaces-in-field-names)

Comment: I will take a look. I appreciate that

Comment: So that didn't work. The question does not solve this issue. Putting brackets as your link suggests does nothing.

Comment: I like how I get downvoted because someone couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I was able to get rid of the curly brackets in the list with the code below. However, still getting None values.                               
self.field_bx['values']= [item for result in self.field_Name() for item in result if item]

Comment: Actually, if you take off the formatting it does return nothing. Try again

Comment: @MelanieLauzon - What do you see if you select a value that contains a space and then print (or otherwise display) `repr(self.field_bx.get())` ?