# Fail to get the correct insert statment for my Access database

Tags: python, ms-access

I want to import data from my Excel file to several tables in my access database. I already mapped all data I wanted to import from my xlsx.file to the column names in the access data tables, but somehow fail to get the insert statement right. Could you help me?

```
#import necessary modules
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

# ODBC connection
connection_string = r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\User\Downloads\OneDrive_2023-07-24\Fragebogen Rohdaten\ArtiPro.accdb;'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)

def import_excel_to_access(excel_file_path, table_mappings):
    # Read the Excel file into a pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\OneDrive_2023-07-24\Fragebogen Rohdaten\A001.xlsx')

    # Create a cursor to execute SQL queries
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    for table_name, column_mapping in table_mappings.items():
        

          # Prepare the INSERT query with selected columns
        insert_query = f"INSERT INTO table_name ({', '.join(column_mapping.values())}) VALUES ({', '.join(['?' for _ in column_mapping.values()])})"
        print(insert_query)
        # Insert data into the Access table
        for row in df.rename(columns=column_mapping)[column_mapping.values()].itertuples(index=False):
            cursor.execute(insert_query, row)

        print(insert_query)
    # Commit the changes and close the connection
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    excel_file_path = r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\OneDrive_2023-07-24\Fragebogen Rohdaten\A001.xlsx'
    table_mappings = {
        '01_Basic Data': {
            'SID': 'SID',
            '1': 'AD intake',
            '2a': 'AD trade name',
            '2b': 'AD substance',
            '3a': 'Drug Dose (in mg)',
            '3b': 'Drug Rhythm',
            '4': 'Age',
            '5': 'Gender',
            '6': 'Ethnicity'
   
        },
        '02_Medication Effect': {
            'SID': 'SID',
            '7': 'Q7',
            '8': 'Q8',
            '8a': 'Q8a',
            '9': 'Q9',
            '9a': 'Q9a',
            '10': 'Q10',
            '10a': 'Q10a',
            '11': 'Q11',
            '11a': 'Q11a',
            '12': 'Q12',
            '12a': 'Q12a',
            '13': 'Q13',
            '13a': 'Q13a',
            '14': 'Q14',
            '14a': 'Q14a',
            '15': 'Q15',
            '16': 'Q16',

            
        },
        
        '03_ADRs': {
            'SID': 'SID',
            'NW_frei': 'ADRs (free speech)',
            '17': 'Q17_dry mouth',
            '17a': 'Q17a_dry mouth',
            '17b': 'Q17b_dry mouth',
            '17c': 'Q17c_dry mouth',
            '17d': 'Q17d_dry mouth',
            '17e': 'Q17e_dry mouth',
            '18': 'Q18_blurred vision',
            '18a': 'Q18a_blurred vision',
            '18b': 'Q18b_blurred vision',
            '18c': 'Q18c_blurred vision',
            '18d': 'Q18d_blurred vision',
            '18e': 'Q18e_blurred vision',
            '19': 'Q19_dizziness',
            '19a': 'Q19a_dizziness',
            '19b': 'Q19b_dizziness',
            '19c': 'Q19c_dizziness',
            '19d': 'Q19d_dizziness',
            '19e': 'Q19e_dizziness',
            '20': 'Q20_fall',
            '20a': 'Q20a_fall',
            '20b': 'Q20b_fall',
            '20c': 'Q20c_fall',
            '20d': 'Q20d_fall',
            '20e': 'Q20e_fall',
            '21': 'Q21_increased appetite',
            '21a': 'Q21a_increased appetite',
            '21b': 'Q21b_increased appetite',
            '21c': 'Q21c_increased appetite',
            '21d': 'Q21d_increased appetite',
            '21e': 'Q21e_increased appetite',
            '22': 'Q22_reduced appetite',
            '22a': 'Q22a_reduced appetite',           
            '22b': 'Q22b_reduced appetite',
            '22c': 'Q22c_reduced appetite',
            '22d': 'Q22d_reduced appetite',
            '22e': 'Q22e_reduced appetite',
            '23': 'Q23_weight gain',
            '23a': 'Q23a_weight gain',
            '23b': 'Q23b_weight gain',
            '23c': 'Q23c_weight gain',
            '23d': 'Q23d_weight gain',
            '23e': 'Q23e_weight gain',
            '24': 'Q24_weight loss',
            '24a': 'Q24a_weight loss',
            '24b': 'Q24b_weight loss',
            '24c': 'Q24c_weight loss',
            '24d': 'Q24d_weight loss',
            '24e': 'Q24e_weight loss',           
            '25': 'Q25_nausea',
            '25a': 'Q25a_nausea',
            '25b': 'Q25b_nausea',
            '25c': 'Q25c_nausea',
            '25d': 'Q25d_nausea',
            '25e': 'Q25e_nausea',
            '26': 'Q26_vomiting',
            '26a': 'Q26a_vomiting',
            '26b': 'Q26b_vomiting',
            '26c': 'Q26c_vomiting',
            '26d': 'Q26d_vomiting',
            '26e': 'Q26e_vomiting',
            '27': 'Q27_bleeding',
            '27a': 'Q27a_bleeding',
            '27aa1': 'Q27aa1_bleeding',
            '27aa2': 'Q27aa2_bleeding',
            '27aa3': 'Q27aa3_bleeding',
            '27aa4': 'Q27aa4_bleeding',
            '27aa5': 'Q27aa5_bleeding',
            '27aa6': 'Q27aa6_bleeding',
            '27b': 'Q27b_bleeding',           
            '27c': 'Q27c_bleeding',
            '27d': 'Q27d_bleeding',
            '27e': 'Q27e_bleeding',
            '28': 'Q28_constipation',
            '28a': 'Q28a_constipation',
            '28b': 'Q28b_constipation',
            '28c': 'Q28c_constipation',
            '28d': 'Q28d_constipation',
            '28e': 'Q28e_constipation',
            '29': 'Q29_diarrhoea',
            '29a': 'Q29a_diarrhoea',
            '29b': 'Q29b_diarrhoea',
            '29c': 'Q29c_diarrhoea',
            '29d': 'Q29d_diarrhoea',
            '29e': 'Q29e_diarrhoea',
            '30': 'Q30_urinary incontinence',           
            '30a': 'Q30a_urinary incontinence',
            '30b': 'Q30b_urinary incontinence',
            '30c': 'Q30c_urinary incontinence',
            '30d': 'Q30d_urinary incontinence',
            '30e': 'Q30e_urinary incontinence',
            '31': 'Q31_urinary retention',
            '31a': 'Q31a_urinary retention',
            '31b': 'Q31b_urinary retention',
            '31c': 'Q31c_urinary retention',
            '31d': 'Q31d_urinary retention',
            '31e': 'Q31e_urinary retention',
            '33': 'Q33',
            'weitere NW_frei': 'Notes'
            
        }
       
    }
    

import_excel_to_access(excel_file_path, table_mappings)
```

But somehow it fails me every time, tried a lot already

```
INSERT INTO table_name (SID, AD intake, AD trade name, AD substance, Drug Dose (in mg), Drug Rhythm, Age, Gender, Ethnicity) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-68b37adef976> in <module>
    174 
    175 
--> 176 import_excel_to_access(excel_file_path, table_mappings)

<ipython-input-24-68b37adef976> in import_excel_to_access(excel_file_path, table_mappings)
     22         # Insert data into the Access table
     23         for row in df.rename(columns=column_mapping)[column_mapping.values()].itertuples(index=False):
---> 24             cursor.execute(insert_query, row)
     25 
     26         print(insert_query)

ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC-Treiber für Microsoft Access] Syntaxfehler in der INSERT INTO-Anweisung. (-3502) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Comment: Those field names with spaces need to be quoted, don’t they? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984124/sql-query-syntax-error-spaces-in-field-names

Comment: A great reason why using column names that require delimit identification is a "no-no".

Comment: depending on the size of the data (and the number of times that you want to do this), an easier method is to create csv files and then import those into the database....  i had to resort to that method yesterday and it was far easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all suggestions. Brackets didn't fix the problem, so I applied the tip from D.L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need *brackets* around some field names:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (SID, [AD intake], [AD trade name], [AD substance], [Drug Dose (in mg)], [Drug Rhythm], Age, Gender, Ethnicity) ...
```